# get a JLabel from JTextPane and change its text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextpane, dom

I add text with JLabel to the JTextPane, then I need to change the text in all JLabel's in the JTextPane. How can I do it?

```
...
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
HTMLEditorKit kit = new CompEditorKit();
HTMLDocument doc = new HTMLDocument();
pane.setEditable(false);
pane.setContentType("text/html");
pane.setEditorKit(kit);
pane.setDocument(doc);
...
kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "Test<object align=\"left\" classid=\"javax.swing.JLabel\"><param name=\"text\" value=\"22\"></object>Test", 0, 0, null);
EditLabels(doc);
...
public void EditLabels(Document doc) {
    if (doc instanceof HTMLDocument) {
        Element elem = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
        ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(elem);
        while ((elem = iterator.next()) != null) {
            AttributeSet attrs = elem.getAttributes();
            Object elementName = attrs.getAttribute(AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute);
            Object o = (elementName != null) ? null : attrs.getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
            if (o instanceof HTML.Tag) {
                if ((HTML.Tag) o == HTML.Tag.OBJECT) {
                    View view = new CompView(elem);
                    //View view = (View)super.create(elem); //ERROR
                    //if (view instanceof JLabel)
                    //{
                    //  ((JLabel) view).setText("NM");
                    //  JLabel label = (JLabel)view;
                    //}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### E.G.

```
View view = new CompView(elem);
((JLabel) view).setText("NM");
error: inconvertible types
  required: JLabel
  found:    View

View view = (View)super.create(elem);
error: cannot find symbol
  symbol: method create(Element)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are mixing two totally different things - JLabel is a separate Swing component that contains text and icon and could be displayed inside any container. And JTextPane is a text editor and its document does NOT contain any separate JLabels, that is why you get "inconvertible types" exception while trying to cast View to JLabel.

View is just a base for various elements created from parsing (in your case) HTML into a structured elements tree.

It might be helpful to read some docs about JTextPane and other similar components:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: mgarin, I added a JLabel in the JTextPane, it exists and I see it http://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2007/07/embedding_swing.html This instruction allows to change JLabel. But if I use insertHTML, instead of setText, I can only change text in added JLabel's, but I can not change text in the JLabel's, which were added before I insert HTML.

Comment: Totally forgot about that feature. Indeed swing components could be inserted into the JTextPane, but what's the point of it? Atleast in case with JLabel - its seems totally meaningless... But anyway about the problem - seems you will have to manipulate the component from the ObjectView. There is an example @ the link you have provided of how to catch the actual component creation - just save the component and do whatever you want with it later...

Comment: Well, save it to some array or map or whatever - just the way you want to keep and use it.